Having problem during installation of torch-scatter on mac with M2 chip (occurs same for Ubuntu)
                                ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch-scatter
  Running setup.py clean for torch-scatter
Failed to build torch-scatter
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (torch-scatter)

How to resolve this issue?
